# Null pointer exception in Java at LinkedList using generics

Tags: java

```
    public class   List_manager<E> {
        Entry<E> first;
        Entry<E> last;
        public void add(E element) {
            Entry<E> e=new Entry(element,last);
            if (first==null) first=last;
        }
        public E get() {
            Entry<E> temp=first;
            first=first.next;
            return temp.data;
        }
        public boolean isEmpty() { return first==null; }


        private static class Entry<E> {
            Entry<E> next;
            E data;
            public Entry(E element,Entry<E> to) {
                data=element;
                next=to;
                to=this;
            }
        }
    }

//now the main class
```

Trying to make a linkedlist

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Point p1=new Point(0,0); // 
        Point p2=new Point(12,5);
        Point p3=new Point(43,12);
        List_manager<Point> l=new List_manager<Point>();
        l.add(p1);
        l.add(p2);
        l.add(p3);
        System.out.println(l.get()); // here is an error occurs
        System.out.println(l.get());
    }
}

// Point
```

Just a simple point

```
public class Point {
    double x; 
    double y;
    public Point(double x,double y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "("+Double.toString(x) + " , " + Double.toString(y) + ")";
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add the Exception stack trace and mark the line in your code where you get your Exception.

Comment: Please add some more text to your question. There's very little explanation of what your problem is.

Comment: you miss instantiate of Entry<E> first

Answer (score 2):

In `add` method you do:

```
if (first==null) first=last;
```

But `last` is never initialized. It's allways `null` an thus `first` is allways `null`.

When you call `get` method, yo do:

```
first=first.next;
```

As `first` is `null` you get the `NullPointerException`

Look a this part of your code:

```
public Entry(E element,Entry<E> to) {
    data=element;
    next=to;
    to=this;
}
```

the last sentence `to = this` does nothing. You are not modifying `last` as it seems you expect.

EDIT ---

You should update `last` in `add` method:

```
public void add(E element) {
    Entry<E> e = new Entry(element, null);
    if (last != null) { last.next = e; }
    last = e;
    if (first == null) first = last;
}
```

Comment: And why if we assign last in add method it works, but when we pass it to the Entry<E> it become null? Or am i missing smt?

Comment: That's because in Java variables are references but doesn't pass method arguments by reference, it passes them by value. So when you modify `to` you change the object referenced by `to` but `last` is unchanged. In this answer you can find a good explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/3963330

Comment: But to refers to the same object as last.

Comment: in add method() Entry<E> e=new Entry(element,last) we pass reference to the object that is being pointed by last and to takes it ... ???

Comment: Initially `last` and `to` _references_ the same object but they are _different_ _variables_. When you do `to = this` then they do not reference the same object anymore. You are not modifying the referenced object. You are modifying the value of variable `to` so it references another object. Variable `last` keeps unchanged.

Comment: You're welcome! if this has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and may help others to find the solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Last is not being set. It will always be null. So first will always be null. When you call get here:

```
public E get() {
   Entry<E> temp=first;
   first=first.next;
   return temp.data;
}
```

You are trying to grab the next value from a null object.

Answer (score 0):

Your variables  `last` and `first` has never been initialised:

```
Entry<E> first;
Entry<E> last;
```

So in your `get()` method you will catch a nullPointerException in this line:

```
first=first.next;
```